# Showing auth_message's

Tags: django, message, authentication

After installing django_message I noticed django has a nice little notification system build-in (Being: Auth_message). I was wondering how can I show them to users? They only appear in the admin panel as for now.

Which template tag can I use to integrate them into the site?
How can I add notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Auth messages are deprecated.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#messages)

Make sure you have `django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages` context processor set in your setting.py. Then you can just use `messages` variable in your templates.

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messagelist">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I think they are now coupled with request not User. See [Adding a message docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#using-messages-in-views-and-templates).